# I am not able to Add as a service Reference in c# visual studio

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Hi I have a one CRM Discovery Service. I can browse this service through browser but cant able to Add it in visual Studio as a web Reference. can anybody please help me why this is happen.
I have a URL like this.

```
https://CRMURL/MSCRMServices/2007/SPLA/CrmDiscoveryService.asmx?WSDL
```

I am getting error like "Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: "

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend you to check the service URL at Settings > Customizations > Developers Resources.plz check the below links for your reference [Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved](http://help.clickdimensions.com/error-metadata-contains-a-reference-that-cannot-be-resolved-crm-2011/)